# Subir Imágenes a un server con PHP y MySQL desde un App hecha en Xamarin Forms

Tags: php, c#, xamarin, upload

Hice un App en `XAMARIN` que sube imágenes capturadas desde el móvil a un server, el API que recibo los datos en hecho en `PHP` y la base de datos `MySQL`.

El problema que tengo es que al subir los datos, lo que guarde como un `Byte[]` lo cual es una foto, llega ala base de datos como un `string` con el contenido `"Sistem.Byte[]"`.

> Código C#:

```
private async void SendReport()
    {

        try
        {

            #region Validaciones

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Detail))
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alerta", "Por favor ingrese una descripción!", "Ok");
                return;
            }

            #endregion

            byte[] imageArray = null;
            if (file != null)
            {
                imageArray = FilesHelper.ReadFully(file.GetStream());
                file.Dispose();
            }

            ImageArray = imageArray;
            double lat = Convert.ToDouble(LatKey);
            double lon = Convert.ToDouble(LonKey);

            var oo = _realm.All<UsersModel>().OrderByDescending(it => it.userId).FirstOrDefault();

            if (oo != null)
            {
                Email = oo.email;
            }

            //Preparo la info para el API
            var url = "http://www.profacoanywhere.com/apilamunicrearreport.php";

            var parm = ImageString;

            var parametros = "?email=" + Email + "&reportType=" + Type.type + "&detail=" + Detail + "&latKey=" + lat + "&lonKey=" + lon + "&photo=" + ImageArray + "";

            //Uso el API
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            var response = await client.GetAsync(parametros);
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //IsRunning = false;
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alerta", result, "Ok");
                return;
            }

            var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);

            if (list is null)
            {
                //IsRunning = false;
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alerta", "No se ha creado el reporte con éxito, por favor reintente!", "Ok");
                return;
            }

            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alerta", "El reporte ha sido enviado, gracias por colaborar con LaMuni!", "Ok");
            //IsRunning = false;


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //IsRunning = false;
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alerta", "Ohhhh... Algo salio mal, por favor reintenta! " + ex.ToString(), "Ok");
            return;

        }


    }
```

> Código en PHP:

```
<?php


    $request_method=$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];

    switch ($request_method) {

        case 'GET':
            //Obtengo los valores del request
            $email = $_GET['email'];
            $reportType = $_GET['reportType'];
            $detail = $_GET['detail'];
            $latKey = $_GET['latKey'];
            $lonKey = $_GET['lonKey'];
            $photo = base64_decode($_GET['photo']);


            if ($email=="" or $reportType=="" or $detail == "" or $latKey =="" or $lonKey =="" or $photo =="" ) {
                creat_report();
                } else {
                    $xml = simplexml_load_file("xml/muniUsrXML.xml");
                    $userDef = (string)$xml->usuarios[0]->usuario;
                    $passDef = (string)$xml->usuarios[0]->pass;
                    $connection=mysqli_connect('localhost',$userDef,$passDef,'LaMuniDB');
                    if ($connection) {
                        creat_report($email,$reportType,$detail,$latKey,$lonKey,$photo);
                        } else {
                            creat_report();
                            }
                    }
                    break;
        default:
            // Invalid Request Method
            header("HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed");
            creat_report();
            break;

    }

    function creat_report($email,$reportType,$detail,$latKey,$lonKey,$photo)
    {
        global $connection;

        $queryInsert="INSERT into reports (reporter,reportType,reportStatus,detail,latKey,lonKey,photo) 
        values ('".$email."','".$reportType."','reportado','".$detail."','".$latKey."','".$lonKey."','".$photo."');";

        $$insert= $connection->query($queryInsert);
        $resCant= mysqli_affected_rows($connection);

        $response=array();

        $response[]= $resCant;

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($response);

    }

    // Close database connection
    mysqli_close($connection);


?>
```

Por favor agradezco de su ayuda!!!

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Enviar imágenes a través de una petición GET no es recomendado, ya que la URL tiene un tamaño máximo que es más pequeño que la mayoría de las imágenes que probablemente tratarás de subir (cerca de 8kb).

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es cambiarlo a un HTTP POST, con el cual puedes enviar archivos del tamaño que quieras.

Si tus archivos son pequeños y quieres intentar enviarlos a través de un GET, el error que tienes es porque el byte array tienes que codificarlo de alguna forma. Prueba con **Convert.ToBase64String(parm)**. En PHP tendrás que decodificar el string base64 para obtener el byte array de vuelta, con **base64_decode**.